# Auto-pagebreak in align environment: Is it possible?

Tags: align, amsmath, page-breaking, warnings

I have a one-line statement of a theorem and a page-long proof of it. I have kept the proof inside

```
\begin{align*}
...
\end{align*}
```

Since there is no break TeXMaker keeps the whole proof in a single page. As a result, the previous page looks like: *Theorem 2.2* in the first line, and the statement in the last line. The middle of the page shows a great white eternal void and the output shows the warning message:

```
"Underfull \vbox has occured while \output is active []"
```

How do I get rid of this? Is there anyway for the align environment to understand the turn of a page and generate auto-pagebreak? Is there any alternative to align which does not have this difficulty?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a `\proof` environment? Then you could use several `align*` environments that will break naturally. I think it's likely that a full-page calculation using `align*` could be improved in clarity by putting some explanatory prose in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

See the section “Vertical spacing and page breaks in multiline displays” in the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath` or `texdoc amsldoc`). It says:

> When the `amsmath` package is in use page breaks between equation lines are normally disallowed; the philosophy is that page breaks in such material should receive individual attention from the author. […]
>
> If you prefer a strategy of letting page breaks fall where they may, even in the middle of a multi-line equation, then you might put `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` in the preamble of your document. An optional argument 1–4 can be used for finer control: `[1]` means allow page breaks, but avoid them as much as possible; values of 2,3,4 mean increasing permissiveness.

You can read [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf#page=12) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

It remains to write `\allowdisplaybreaks`.